# Can I embed a browser inside a screensaver? On both Windows and Macs?

Tags: browser, screensaver

Here's the deal. I've animated + coded a variety of 'screensavers' in Actionscript3/Flash. They make extensive use of the timeline, AS3 code, the TweenLite library, and embedded fonts. That's the limit of my programming knowledge. I've tried, to no avail, to convert my .SWFs into screensaver files using a variety of software, such as InstantStorm. Somehow it never works, the code never executes properly, it's a disaster.

So, I'm wondering if it's possible to make a screensaver that simply contains an embedded browser, and have it point to my .SWF file, hosted on my web-server. Basically, imagine a full-screen website acting as a screensaver.

If this is possible, what is the EASIEST and FASTEST way for me to whip up a solution for both PCs and Macs? Language, etc. I'm hoping something that has a library I can simply draw from to embed the browser view :)

Comment: Found this suggestion to work: http://travisepperson.blogspot.com/2010/02/use-any-webpage-as-your-screen-saver.html - now if I can just get it to auto-login to websites that have login/password.

Comment: @RichardJ I gave that app a try, but it wouldn't render my desired web page. See my answer below for what I ultimately got to work.

Answer (score 1):

My startup is developing a product to do exactly this, it's called [Screensaver Ninja](https://Screensaver.Ninja) and you can find it at https://Screensaver.Ninja.

You can set many different web pages with different timers. The configuration tool allows you log in and navigate to the page you want to display:

[image]

It uses WebKit, on Mac OS X it uses Safari's and on Windows it uses Chrome's and in both cases it has a separate session from any other browser installed on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small Windows-only solution:

https://github.com/cwc/web-page-screensaver/releases

Answer (score 0):

You could modify this open-source one for the Mac so that it's hard-coded to your URL:

http://www.liquidx.net/blog/2010/11/13/webviewscreensaver-for-mac/

Modify `hasConfigureSheet()` to return `NO` and change the URL in `kScreenSaverDefaultURL`. And change the name!